# Countdown timer expires start a different countdown

Tags: javascript, timer

I have the following code. I want when this timer expires, another timer should start instead of expired text.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 25, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Days " + hours + " Hrs "
    + minutes + " Min " + seconds + " Sec ";

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "T**imer Expired - instead of this another timer**";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what **exact** problem you have? At the moment it is hard to get what you want to know/achieve.

Comment: There is no specific problem or question stated.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick. Each time the counter get to 0, you redefined your count down to the same amount of time there was initially between countDownDate and Now. If this amount is variable, you might modify the assignment of distanceToAdd

```js
 
 // Changed the value to reach for the demo
 var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 20000;
     // Fixed Value to add each time the counter get to 0
     var distanceToAdd = countDownDate - new Date().getTime();   

 var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (distance < 0) {
        //Add Time to your timer goal instead of canceling interval
        countDownDate += distanceToAdd;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "        Days " + hours + " Hrs "
        + minutes + " Min " + seconds + " Sec ";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <div id="demo"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function, and call it every time the timer is finished.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1 ;
  setTimer(i) ;
}) ;


function setTimer(i) {
  var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 3000 ;

  var x = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime() ;

      var distance = countDownDate - now ;

      if (distance < 0) {
          clearInterval(x);
          console.log("Timer " + i + " Finished. New Timer Stated!") ;
          setTimer(i+1) ;
      }
      else {
      console.log("Timer " + i + " Running") ;
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```